# How turbocharger mobile charger works?

Tags: power-supply, raspberry-pi, charger, adapter

I have found a turbocharger from a motorola device which has 5V, 9V and 12V outputs.
I want to use this charger to run raspberry pi 4. 
I need to know how tutbocharger changes the voltage?
I am scared of the fact that it can supply 12 volt too. Which will burn the board.

Comment: Where are your links to hardware?

Comment: 1) What charger? Be more specific 2) You mention "output**s**" which suggests multiple outputs, then just use the 5 V output and not the others. 3) If you actually mean that the single output of the adapter can output 5 V, 9 V or 12 V then it will output 5 V **until the adapter is instructed to output more**. This can only be done by devices which are designed for that, for example those supporting QuickCharge. As long as the adapter works properly it will only output 5 V and not more so is safe to use with an RPi. But why not simply use a 5 V only adapter?